# Vue 3 - Composition Api - Typescript -> type of emit

Tags: typescript, vue.js, composition

I'm starting with VUE 3 and the composition api using Typescript for the first time.
I have the setup method like the following:
`setup(props: { widgetType: string; displayType: string; trigger: number }, { emit })` 
Now, when I'm building this file, I get the error "Binding element 'emit' implicitly has an 'any' type.".
I do not know how to fix this. I tried different solutions from the web but nothing worked.
Can anybody help me?
Regards
Chris

Comment: How have you defined your component?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your component with the `defineComponent` method and apply the correct type to props. If you are using single file components it would look something like this

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        widgetType: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        displayType: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        trigger: {
            type: number,
            required: true
        }
    },

    setup(props, { emit }) {

        // Rest of your setup code here
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For example correct typing with component "App" and composable "useModal"

App:

```
<script lang="ts"> 
 import {defineComponent, SetupContext, ComponentPropsOptions} from 'vue';
 import {useModal} from '@/composable/useModal';
                    
 export default defineComponent({
   name: 'App',
   emits: ['openModal'],
   setup(props: ComponentPropsOptions, {emit}: SetupContext) {
     const openModal = useModal({emit});
                    
     return {openModal};
   }
});
</script>
```

useModal:

```
import {SetupContext} from 'vue';

interface UseModalProps {
  emit: SetupContext['emit'];
}

export function useModal({emit}: UseModalProps) {
  function openModal({title, type}: {title: string; type: string}): void {
    emit('openModal', {title, type});
  }

  return {openModal};
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you still define `emits: ['openModal']` in the App ?

Comment: You are right, I have edited the example.